# clang: error: cannot specify both '-fobjc-arc' and '-fobjc-gc'

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I do have **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** set to **YES**, but I have
**Objective-C Garbage Collection** set to **Unsupported**

So I don't see how -fobjc-gc could be getting set.  Is there something else that also sets it that I haven't noticed?  I've tried a clean build, so it's not something sticking around.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your individual files is being compiled with `-fobjc-gc`?

Comment: I'm not setting compilation options on individual files.  Unless there's a framework - already compiled - that's causing this.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, indirectly, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). It turns out, that to get rid of garbage collection, I need to BOTH turn off garbage collection in the compiler settings when I click on Build Settings under the Project, and under the Target.  If they disagree, the target (which is the one I didn't notice) overrides.  No amount of playing with the settings at the project level was fixing that.

Comment: Well, technically you only needed to turn it off at the target level, since project settings only apply if the target doesn't specify anything. But it doesn't really make sense to have it on at the project level if you're not using it on any targets. Alternatively, you could just delete the target level setting and let it inherit from the project setting.